# How to achieve Fewer HTTP Requests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yslow

I have analyzed my site in GTmetrix site in the Yslow section it has shown me that

```
This page has 6 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
```

How to find out in which location of javascripts i should combine.

does any one have previous experience on minimizing Http requests.

Comment: read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: As for finding out the location, doesn't your analyzer tell you?  If not, just look at the page source, or the network tab in chrome inspector (or the equivalent in your browser).  If the javascript files are loaded from a different site then you won't be able to concatenate the externally loaded ones.  However, you can download them into your app/assets folder, and link to the local ones instead, and use the concatenated version of them in production mode (this is explained in the link above).

Comment: BTW there are several strategies for reducing the number of requests made by your pages:  concatenated js/css (which will require you to have copied the files locally), combined image files (aka "image maps", where all the icons are on a single png for example, and 'singled out' via css).  To make the most of combined image files, try to avoid img tags in your markup: instead, use css to apply all images, from the aforementioned image maps. Browser caching is another important strategy, reducing the number of requests made on subsequent visits https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html